# Acces to postdata from the POST request

Tags: json, vb.net, post, asp.net-web-api

I create an `ASP.NET Web Api` to build my RESTful services so when I add a `Web API 2 controller` the action for POST is added like this

```
'POST: api/example
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

End Sub
```

Then I use `SoapUI` and create a `REST` proyect to test it. In the proyect I make the post request with json data so when I run it returns me the state `204 No Content` and using `HTTP Analyzer` I can see in the Post Data section the json that was send in the request but **I need to take that Json, modify and return a new json as response, how can i do it** I tried to use `HttpResponseMessage` but I can't Access to the post data in the request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the formbody and replace the string with class (representation of JSON )